# Can two GraphQLSchema instances be merged?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm looking to write a function like `Object.assign` or `_.merge`, but that operates on `GraphQLSchema` objects.

Suppose I have two instances of [`GraphQLSchema`](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlschema), call them Base and Other, and I would like to merge Other into Base to produce a new instance Result such that

- Fields present in exactly one of Base or Other are defined in Result by their original `GraphQLFieldConfig`
- Fields present in both are reduced to the `GraphQLFieldConfig` in Other.

It looks as though there is no documented means to do this. Is that correct? If I went the (considerably more dangerous) undocumented route, I've noticed that I could exploit internal properties of the object:

[image], but I'd prefer not to do that.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the library [merge-graphql-schemas](https://github.com/okgrow/merge-graphql-schemas). I think this may help you

Comment: This library seems do not support merge `GraphQLSchema` objects. It only supports merge graphql string schema.

Answer (score 2):

Using mergeSchemas from 'graphql-tools', you can merge GraphQLSchema objects

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-stitching.html#mergeSchemas

```
import { mergeSchemas } from 'graphql-tools';

const schema = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: [
    chirpSchema,
    authorSchema,
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
const { mergeTypes } = require('merge-graphql-schemas');
const { printSchema, parse } = require('graphql');

const typeArray = graphqlSchemas.map(printSchema);
const schema = mergeTypes(typeArray, { all: true });

  try {
    parse(schema);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
```

`graphqlSchemas` is `GraphQLSchema` type. For my case, it's array.

`printSchema` convert `GraphQLSchema` to string template schema.

`mergeTypes` merge all string template schemas into one.

And, for safety, use `try/catch` to validate the schema is valid or not.